# What schematic symbol is used for a flex cable?

Tags: schematics, kicad, fpc, ffc, flex

Generally asking, but primarily for KiCad, what is the schematic symbol typically used for FPC/FFC/flex cables?

That is to say, the flat end which is sometimes stiffened and does not have a connector like in the following image:

[image: FFC]

In KiCad, would the above cable be represented by `Connector_Generic > Conn_01x14`?

[image: KiCad Connector_Generic > Conn_01x14]

Or is this something that a [`Bus`](https://docs.kicad.org/7.0/en/eeschema/eeschema.html#buses) in KiCad can be used for? I doubt this because this appears to only be a way to make connections within a project, while in the use-case I'm asking about there is no further connection after this FFC (in the context of the project).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is essentially the same as an edge connector on a normal PC board, so I'd use a generic connector as the schematic symbol.